# How to Show Buttons according to screen touch in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, view

I have need to implement a functionality in which I have to show Button according to touch move. Suppose I am starting to touch move for open curtain view
to navigate an other screen Like bellow Image.[image]

As Like in above image once we start slide up, I want to bellow behaviour:
if slide Up 10 % then button(B1, B2) visible smoothly up to 10% and rest button will not visible at this point of Slide up. But when SlideUp upto 30% then Button B1, B2 will be visible 50% and A1 and A2 button will be visible 20% and middle textview still not visible at alla after more that 60% slide up all controls will be visible.
           I have try by animation Interpolater but behavior is totally different. Anyone could guide me. Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.i("Coord", "Val :: "+(1030 - event.getX()));
            if(544 - event.getX() >= 0){
                Log.i("Coord", "Show");
                mRecentMedia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mCamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mMenuar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                mRecentMedia.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator(0.5f)).start();
                mCamera.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator(2)).start();
                mMenuar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator(2)).start();

            }else{
                Log.i("Coord", "Hide");
                mRecentMedia.animate().translationY(200).setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator(0.5f)).start();
                mCamera.animate().translationY(200).setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator(2)).start();
                mMenuar.animate().translationY(200).setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator(2)).start();
            }
            break;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

But above is not working for me. Will not manage animation as per Slide position.

I have Also make same animation but that will not work, Because once animation start will not manage it as per SlideUp Code is bellow:-

```
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        AnimatorSet set1 = new AnimatorSet();
        set1.playTogether(
                Glider.glide(Skill.CubicEaseOut, 1500, ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mRecentMedia, "translationY", 210, 0))
        );
        set1.setStartDelay(300);

        set.playTogether(
                Glider.glide(Skill.CubicEaseOut, 1500, ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCamera, "translationY", 210, 0))
        );

        set.playTogether(
                Glider.glide(Skill.CubicEaseOut, 1500, ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mMenuar, "translationY", 210, 0))
        );

        set1.setDuration(1500);
        set1.start();
        set.setDuration(1500);
        set.start();
```

Comment: why not just place them in scroll view such that they accomodate your specification? I don't see any reason for doing this manually.

Comment: @Usama Zafar  What are you trying to say, These button are at bottom of next screen, which will be visible as per SlideUp like in image and Like CubicEaseOut animation but this animation didnt controll as per Sliding

Comment: I don't think animation is the correct way to go about this. Take a look [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.tw/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) and look up CoordinatorLayout. Basically you want to set translation on those button views based on the scrolled position of an outer ScrollView.

Comment: I think Some One is here only for -ve voting, I think stackoverflow should have block these type of more over intelligent guy